# Looker Explore -Hide one of the dimension and group in the visualization

Tags: visualization, looker-studio

I have two dimensions "Week" and "Date" and one measure in my data . I am trying to hide "Date" using the gear method  "Hide from visualization" and display only Week with the measure in the visualization. However, it does not group the "Week" . i would like to group the week together in the visualization

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want to remove the Date dimension. If you remove it, Looker will automatically group by Week.

Alternatively, you can create a new dimension that is formatted similar to `Date`, but that is consistent for unique values of `Week`, to prevent a fan-out on the (hidden) `Date` field in your viz. You can do this in Lookml or SQL. For example, right now you have something like:

| Week | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2022/W40 | 2022-09-23 |
| 2022/W40 | 2022-09-22 |
| 2022/W40 | 2022-09-21 |

But you need to produce something like

| Week | Week Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2022/W40 | 2022-09-19 |
| 2022/W40 | 2022-09-19 |
| 2022/W40 | 2022-09-19 |

Comment: Hello tconbeer , i would like to use the date in the table calculation. Therefore, I did not remove in the data table.